# laravel only 'sometimes' forbidden error 403

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I am practicing laravel and already uploaded to production, then i have some problem and it happened just 'sometimes', when i  move to move route (move to move menu / path) suddenly forbidden access 403 <<<< only sometimes, but if i clear browser my route(menu/path) worked again no problem and it happened again when left lapse of time

virtualhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>



  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tes/app/public
  <Directory /var/www/html/tes/app/public>
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Custom log file locations
  #LogLevel warn
  #ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-tes.log
  #CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-tes.log combined

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

my route

```
Route::get('/', 'PenggunaController@index');
Route::post('/submitlogin', 'PenggunaController@submitlogin');

Route::prefix('workorder')->group(function () {
    Route::get('inprogress', 'WorkorderController@fetchinprogress');
});
Route::prefix('request')->group(function () {
    Route::get('inprogress', 'MyreqController@index');
    Route::get('/myreq/{id}/{flag}', 'MyreqController@flag');
    Route::get('/emp', 'MyreqController@emp');
    Route::get('history', 'MyreqController@history');
});
```

thank you for attention

Comment: add the route definition for that route and any middleware you are assigning

Comment: i don't use middleware

Comment: should still have a route defined somewhere

Comment: all route sometimes 403 forbidden

Comment: "it happened again when left lapse of time" - how long? The default session timeout is 2 hours in a new Laravel install

Comment: @TravisBritz uncertain, sometimes every 15 minutes , 30 minutes